# Neo4j bolt driver ClientException

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api, neo4j-bolt

I have loaded about 20000 odd nodes from the consumer complaints csv file available in the neo4j load csv example. I am using Neo4j bolt driver in my java class to query .

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost/trialschema", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "neo" ) );
        Session session = driver.session();


        StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH(n)-[r]-(m) return n,type(r),m limit 10" );
        Map<String,Object> resultOfQuery = processResult(result);

          session.close();
          driver.close();
          return returnMap ;
```

But when I am trying to loop through this StatementResult, inside processResult Method,  I get the below exception

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500).
>       org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Trying to read message
>   complete ending '00 00' while there are more data left in the message
>   content unread: buffer [41 49 4e 53 54 b3 4e c9 77 af 91 89 43 6f 6d
>   70 6c 61 69 6e 74 a1 82 69 64 ca 00 1d 13 40 00 00 00 46 b1 71 93 b3
>   4e 07 91 87 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 a1 84 6e 61 6d 65 8f 42 41 4e 4b 20
>   4f 46 20 41 4d 45 52 49 43 41 87 41 47 41 49 4e 53 54 b3 4e c9 77 9c
>   91 89 43 6f 6d 70 6c 61 69 6e 74 a1 82 69 64 ca 00 1b d4 06 00 00 00
>   46 b1 71 93 b3 4e 07 91 87 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 a1 84 6e 61 6d 65 8f
>   42 41 4e 4b 20 4f 46 20 41 4d 45 52 49 43 41 87 41 47 41 49 4e 53 54
>   b3 4e c9 77 a4 91 89 43 6f 6d 70 6c 61 69 6e 74 a1 82 69 64 ca 00 1d
>   3c 54 00 00 00 46 b1 71 93 b3 4e 07 91 87 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 a1 84
>   6e 61 6d 65 8f 42 41 4e 4b 20 4f 46 20 41 4d 45 52 49 43 41 87 41 47
>   41 49 4e 53 54 b3 4e c9 77 95 91 89 43 6f 6d 70 6c 61 69 6e 74 a1 82
>   69 64 ca 00 0b 56 ca 00 00 00 46 b1 71 93 b3 4e 07 91 87 43 6f 6d 70
>   61 6e 79 a1 84 6e 61 6d 65 8f 42 41 4e 4b 20 4f 46 20 41 4d 45 52 49
>   43 41 --------------unread chunk size 11075

I don't get this issue if I am trying to fetch only a small result by limiting the result to 50 or 100 . Can someone help ?

Comment: What does processResults do?

Comment: Which version of the driver did you use? Can you try with 1.0.3 ?

Comment: Thanks. Using 1.0.3 solved the issue. :)